# A question about a bounded linear surjective operator

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

This is a question from Rudin's Functional Analysis.

Let $T\in \mathcal B(X,Y)$ and $T(X)=Y$. I have to prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\{S\in \mathcal B(X,Y):S(X)=Y\}\supset B_{\delta}(T)$, where the ball is with respect to the metric generated by the operator norm.

I could not proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct direction of inclusion?  Could it be that you're meant to prove $\{S\in \mathcal B(X,Y):S(X)=Y\}\supset B_{\delta}(T)$ (i.e. that the surjective operators form an open set)?

Comment: Yes. I have mistaken. Accordingly I have changed the post.

Comment: @Anupam see Robert Israel's answer on the linked post.  Does that suit your needs?

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom Yes that very much suits my need. Thanks.